# Wpf MVVM How to handle TextBox "paste event" in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, paste

I develop application with using `MVVM` pattern. I using MVVMLight library to do this. So if I need to handle `TextBox` `TextChange` event I write in XAML:

```
<I:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
    <I:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PropertyGridTextChange}"/>
</I:EventTrigger>
```

where `PropertyGridTextChange` is `Command` in `ViewModel`. But `TextBox` has no `Paste` event!

**[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b52b5b99-1ee0-44b9-bfa5-7186556069ab/detecting-paste-into-textbox)** solution only works if application don't use `MVVM` pattern, because you need to have link on `TextBox`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Important detail - `TextBox` placed within `DataTemplate`.
I have no idea how can I handle "paste event". 
I want `PasteCommand` to be invoked when I paste text into `TextBox`. And I need that `TextBox.Text` or `TextBox` itself to be passed as parameter into `PasteCommandMethod`.

```
private RelayCommand<Object> _pasteCommand;
public RelayCommand<Object> PasteCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _pasteCommand ?? (_pasteCommand =
            new RelayCommand<Object>(PasteCommandMethod));
    }
}

private void PasteCommandMethod(Object obj)
{
}
```

Comment: What do you want to the view model to do in case text is pasted?

Comment: I want some `Command` to be invoked.

Comment: Ok, I should have phrased that question more accurately: why do you specifically want to handle copy&paste events instead of just data binding the Text property?

Comment: When I paste some text into `TextBox` I want to be able edit that text. Actually I need to replace "return carrige" symbols on "space" symbols.

Comment: Just data bind a `string` to the `TextBox.Text` property then you can do your work in the `string` property setter.

Comment: @ Sheridan I cannot do that. `TextBox` placed in `DataTemplate`, it is not single `TextBox` in `Window`. So I cannot bind its `Text` property to particular `VM` property (this property already bound). And even I could, I don't want that my `work` is executed every time as `Text` property changes.

Comment: Personally I'd just go for the pragmatic solution. If MVVM makes my hard life in an instance I'll try to find a better solution for that case.

Comment: @ Dirk, I cannot refuse MVVM, cause it is already working project. It is too hard to rewrite it. :)

Comment: Perhaps in this case you have a couple of lines of code beind the xaml to interact with the VM . . . not pure MVVM but I see some of the examples do this.

Answer (score 9):

I can suggest answer on my question.

**Class-helper.**

```
public class TextBoxPasteBehavior 
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty PasteCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "PasteCommand",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(TextBoxPasteBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PasteCommandChanged)
    );

public static ICommand GetPasteCommand(DependencyObject target)
{
    return (ICommand)target.GetValue(PasteCommandProperty);
}

public static void SetPasteCommand(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
{
    target.SetValue(PasteCommandProperty, value);
}

static void PasteCommandChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    var newValue = (ICommand)e.NewValue;

    if (newValue != null)
        textBox.AddHandler(CommandManager.ExecutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CommandExecuted), true);
    else
        textBox.RemoveHandler(CommandManager.ExecutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CommandExecuted));

}

static void CommandExecuted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)e).Command != ApplicationCommands.Paste) return;

    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    var command = GetPasteCommand(textBox);

    if (command.CanExecute(null))
        command.Execute(textBox);
}
}
```

**Using in XAML.** In `TextBox` as attribute.

```
TextBoxPasteBehavior.PasteCommand="{Binding PropertyGridTextPasted}"
```

`PropertyGridTextPasted` - Command in the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this kind of problem too in recent days.  My first approach would be to have a property in the VM that is bound to the text box (which I am sure you already have).  Then bind an ICommand to an event to handle the on paste event:

```
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DocRowEdit}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

you need to define the namespace in the proper part of the XAML code, and then put the interaction triggers in as part of the textbox definition.  Here I am capturing the RowEditEnding event to do some stuff similar to what you are attempting.

The command binding is another piece, let me know if you need more information on how that needs to be set up.

Comment: I'm realizing that this probably does not work inside a data template . . .

Comment: did you mean 'as part of the `DataGrid` definition'? Because `TextBox` has no `RowEditEditing` event.

Comment: @monstr yes I did . . . just showing how I implement.  But the answer is not helpful because I misread his question . . . before coffee I think, but I missed the part that you are wanting to do this in a data template . . . which I cannot speak to as I have not yet tried that.

Comment: @ Paul Gibson Yep, it doesn't work both with `DataTemplate` and without `DataTemplate`

Comment: @ Paul Gibson, look my answer if you are interested