# MVVM catch textbox paste event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have tried to transform this this (from old application) to MVVM pattern but I don't see how I will do it.

```
textBoxLoader.AddHandler(CommandManager.ExecutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(PasteFunction), true);

    private void PasteFunction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {       
            if ((e as ExecutedRoutedEventArgs).Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
            {             
                // verify that the textbox handled the paste command

                textBoxLoader.IsEnabled = false;
                List<string[]> MachineList = new List<string[]>();
                List<string> list = new List<string>(Regex.Split(textBoxLoader.Text, Environment.NewLine));
}}
```

How can I reproduce this and call  command from WPF TextBox *Paste event*?
I can successfully bind *Enter Key event*, but how do I bind *Paste event*?

Below is a code snippet on how I am binding a *Icommand* in new MVVM (*Enter Key listener*)

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBoxLoader}"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Try this thread...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346652/wpf-mvvm-how-to-handle-textbox-paste-event-in-the-viewmodel/28365540#28365540

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In view :

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120" Height="200"/>
```

In view model :

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { SetProperty(ref text, value); }
    }
}
```

In this way, when you paste the text or press **Ctrl+V** the Text value is updated and PropertyChanged event is raised. Thus you can identify the pasted text into textbox.

If you want to identify Ctrl+V for some special reason, try this :

```
void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.V)
    {
          // Your action
    }
}
```

Comment: since its mvvm i should have no back code if i use previewkeydown i can use the function i posted on top :private void PasteFunction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e). iahve to make everithing between view/view model using Icommand and binding to me

Comment: If you're not happy with the propertychanged thing too, then try something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346652/wpf-mvvm-how-to-handle-textbox-paste-event-in-the-viewmodel 
**You can't have an empty code behind and achieve what you need, unless you are doing it with propertychanged alone.** You can have view related code in code behind always. It doesnt violate MVVM pattern. Anyways, give the above link a try. It helps to route the **Paste** command to the view model.

Comment: yeah irealized i can't act on paste command in pure wpf-MV but you pointed me to just corect code  to care only on propertyChanged.so i dont  even need care at "Enter" or "ctrl+v" .

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need to completely eliminate the enter key press command. I also use similar command for saving the text and all.  The only thing is it is difficult to achieve **Ctrl+v** behavior and all.  But it's upto you to decide on how to design it. If it's really needed,  you could even handle pasted event in code behind and route it to view model.  But since you need a clean code behind,  this would be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM the textbox is bound to a property on the VM. Why not simply subscribe to the VM's notify property change (*could be done on the VM itself actually*) and look for a change reported on that bound property.

Once a change notification is sent, do the logic needed.

**Example**

This working example, *wouldn't be used in the real world because the work would be done in the setter of `Name`*, demonstrates how to subscribe to the notify event. When `Name` is changed the VM catches the change from the event and `FullName` is computed and the property changed is raised for `FullName` from the subscription.

```
public class ExampleVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public ExampleVM()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += (s, a) =>
        {
            if (a.PropertyName == "Name")
            {
                FullName = $"Mr. {Name}";
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

C# 6 coding is used, but can be rewritten in any other version of C#.

Comment: have you an exemple of this?

Comment: @Zwan see example.